# Question about a proof in Rudin's book - annihilators

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm reading the proof of the following theorem in Rudin's "Functional Analysis":

Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a Banach space $X$. 
The Hahn-Banach theorem extends each $m^* \in M^*$ to a functional $x^* \in X^*$. 
Define $\sigma (m^*) = x^* + M^{\perp}$. 
Then $\sigma$ is an isometric isomorphism of $M^*$ onto $X^*/M^{\perp}$.

My problem is this part of the proof:

Fix $m^* \in M^*$. If $x^* \in X^*$ extends $m^*$, it is obvious that $||m^*|| \le ||x^*||$

The greatest lower bound of the numbers $||x^*||$ so obtained is $||x^* + M^{\perp}||$, by the 
definition of the quotient norm. Hence 
$||m^*|| \le || \sigma (m^*) ||  \le ||x^*||$ 
But Theorem 3.3 furnishes an extension $x^*$ of $m^*$ with $||x^*|| = ||m^*||$. It follows 
that $|| \sigma( m^*)|| = ||m^*||$.

3.3 Theorem

Suppose $M$ is a subspace of a vector space $X$, $p$ is a seminorm on $X$, 
and $f$ is a linear functional on $M$ such that 
$|f(x)| \le p(x) \ \  (x \in M)$. 
Then $f$ extends to a linear functional $\Lambda$ on $X$ that satisfies 
$| \Lambda x | \le p(x)$  $ \ \ (x \in X)$.

What I don't see is how theorem 3.3 implies the equality of norms: $||x^*|| = ||m^*||$ and why is $||m^*|| \le ||x^*||$ (in the first line). It would be clear to me if $||x^*||$ was a regular norm of a linear mapping (we take the supremum over a bigger set) but I don't see it if it is a quotient norm.

Could you explain that to me?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first line of the proof, $\| x^*\|$ means the regular norm.

We want to see that $\| m^*\|=\| \sigma(m^*)\|$. Till the use of Theorem 3.3 we have seen
that 
$$\| m^*\|\leq \|\sigma(m^*)\|\quad \text{and} \quad \|\sigma(m^*)\|\leq \| x^*\|, \tag1 $$ 
where $x^*$
is any extension of $m^*$.

Let $p:X \to [0,\infty)$ be defined by $p(x)=\| m^*\| \| x\|$. It is obvious that this is a 
seminorm (actually a norm) on $X$ such that
$$ |m^*(x)|\leq p(x)\quad \forall x\in M. $$
By Theorem 3.3, there exists an extension $x^*$ of $m^*$ such that
$$ |x^*(x)|\leq p(x)\quad \forall x\in X. $$
Hence $|x^*(x)|\leq \| m^*\| \| x\|$ forall $x\in X$ which gives $\| x^*\|\leq \| m^*\|$
and consequently $\| x^*\|= \| m^*\|$ because $\| x^*\|$ cannot be strictly smaller than $ \| m^*\|$. This and (1) together give $\| m^*\|=\| \sigma(m^*)\|$.