# Question on Rudin's functional analysis Theorem 4.9

Tags: functional-analysis

$M$ is a closed subspace of a Banach space $X$

part (a) of theorem 4.9 proves $M^*=X^*/M^{\perp}$ ("=" means isometric isomorphism)

He constructed a map $\sigma:M^*\to X^*/M^{\perp}$

$$\sigma (m^*)=x^*+M^{\perp}$$

and has already proved $\sigma$ is a isomorphism, we need to show $\sigma$ is isometric, the proof is

> Fix $m^* \in M^*$. If $x^* \in X^*$ extends $m^*$, it is obvious that $||m^*|| \le ||x^*||$
>
> The greatest lower bound of the numbers $||x^*||$ so obtained is $||x^* + M^{\perp}||$, by the definition of the quotient norm. Hence
> $||m^*|| \le || \sigma (m^*) ||  \le ||x^*||$
> But Theorem 3.3 furnishes an extension $x^*$ of $m^*$ with $||x^*|| = ||m^*||$. It follows
> that $|| \sigma( m^*)|| = ||m^*||$.

I don't understand "The greatest lower bound of the numbers $||x^*||$ so obtained is $||x^* + M^{\perp}||$", what does "so obtained" mean? and how to get $||m^*|| \le || \sigma (m^*) ||  \le ||x^*||$  from the definition of quotient norm?

(quotient norm : $\|\sigma(m^*)\|=\|x^*+M^{\perp}\|=\inf\{\|x^*-y\|,y\in M^{\perp}\}$)

(if my description of the theorem is unclear, your can refer to this post [Question about a proof in Rudin's book - annihilators](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095671/question-about-a-proof-in-rudins-book-annihilators))